# How to create a proxy of an interface in Java?

Tags: java, proxy, mocking, dynamic-proxy

How can one create a proxy for an interface without creating a class that implements it?

I have a concrete example: I have an interface, Contact, and need to create a proxy object that acts as a Contact. This proxy object will be used for running some TestNG tests.

I have tried using the JDK approach but could find only examples that needed an actual implementation of that interface.

I also found that jasssist may help me in this problem and tried implementing a simple example that seems to be working until I get an Out of Memory error. Here is a snippet of what I am doing:

```
import javassist.util.proxy.MethodFilter;
import javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler;
import javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory

protected final T createMock(final Class<T> clazz) {
    final ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
    factory.setInterfaces(new Class[] { clazz });
    factory.setFilter(new MethodFilter() {
        public final boolean isHandled(final Method m) {
            // ignore finalize()
            return !m.getName().equals("finalize");
        }
    });

    final MethodHandler handler = createDefaultMethodHandler();
    try {
        return (T) factory.create(new Class<?>[0], new Object[0], handler);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
private MethodHandler createDefaultMethodHandler() {
    return new MethodHandler() {
        public final Object invoke(final Object self,
                final Method thisMethod, final Method proceed,
                final Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Handling " + thisMethod
                    + " via the method handler");
            return thisMethod.invoke(self, args);
        }
    };
}
```

Remember that the parameter of the createMock() method will be an interface.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you ignore calls to finalize? Maybe that has something to do with your OutOfMemory exceptions!?

Comment: The error still occurs if I take into consideration the finalize() method. I think the problem is somewhere else, because I get the same errors when using javassist and commons-proxy. For the moment, I think I will provide an simple implementation for each interface that needs to be tested because I invested some time into this problem and could make it work.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method `newProxyInstance` of `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`.
Ex:

```
    Proxy.newProxyInstance(iClazz.getClassLoader(),
        new Class[]{iClazz},
        new YourInvocationHandler())
```

`iClazz` is the class of your interface and `YourInvocationHandler` is an instance of `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler`

Answer (score 2):

[commons-proxy](http://commons.apache.org/proxy/) aims at simplifying the task.

What you want is an invoker proxy (without a target object). So you can use:

```
ProxyFactory factory = new JavassistProxyFactory();
Object result = 
      factory.createInvokerProxy(invoker, new Class[] {YourInterface.class});
```

And your `invoker` must implement the `Invoker` interface, whose `invoke` method will be called on each method invocation. (4 times the word "invoke" here)

Note that commons-proxy uses the preferred underlying proxying mechanism - in the above example it's javassist.

---

However, you seem to need the proxy for mocking purposes. With [mockito](http://mockito.org/) this is as easy as:

```
YourInterface yourMock = mock(YourInterface.class);
when(yourMock.someMethod()).thenReturn(yourPreferredResult);
```

Comment: i will try the commons proxy. note that my provided snippet works but the tests take very long to run, throw a lot of InvocationTargetExceptions and then OutOfMemory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interesting in mocking I would suggest to use a framework.

EasyMock ( http://easymock.org/ ) or JMock ( http://www.jmock.org/ ) might fit.

To create a proxy yourself you can use the class `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`.

Comment: I looked at the mocking frameworks and tried EasyMock but I just wanted to create a proxy and not set some expectations, behavior and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Exampledepot has a simple snippet for how to create an interface proxy based on `java.lang.reflect.proxy` at http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/java.lang.reflect/ProxyClass.html

You just need to provide functionality for the `invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)` in your own code.

---

EDIT:  Based on comments it appears that the class you  do not want is the *interface* class, not the *implementation* class.   In that case there is no way around byte code manipulation.  You may want to look at Javassist which contains a snippet compiler.

Comment: thanks, but that example needs an implementation of the interface and I do not want to create an actual implementation.

Comment: this is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In your code i did the following

```
//              return thisMethod.invoke(self, args);
            return null;
```

and i got the following result

```
Handling public abstract void org.rege.instruments.IPerson.setName(java.lang.String) via the method handler
```

Is this what did you wanted? 
As you can see the OutOfMemory was produced by a recursive call to your invoke.